# Example about monotonic function makes the IVT false

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to give an example to show the the IVT" the Intermediate Value Theorem" becomes false when $f$ is continuous is replaced with f being monotonic (increasing or decreasing), or $f$ being strictly monotonic (increasing or decreasing).

I am getting stuck with this question because I have a proposition says for a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$  which is both continuous function and strictly monotonic increasing, we have that $f$ is bijection from $[a,b] \rightarrow[f(a),f(b)]$.

So I am thinking that the question aims to find continuous function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that when we make it monotonic decreasing, which still continues  since we take a subset $[a',b'] \subseteq[a,b]$ that makes $f$ monotonic decreasing, we can find such $c$ in $[f(a'),f(b')]$ such that there is no $x$ in $[a',b']$ such that $f(x)=c$..

Am I on the right track ??
I need any help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: The IVT implies that the function you seek can't be continuous. Fortunately, **any** strictly monotone discontinuous function does what you want.

Comment: Thank youuuuu so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: $f:[0,2]\rightarrow[0,3]$, $f(x)=x$, for $x\in[0,1)$, $f(x)=x+1$, for $x\in[1,2]$, there is no $c\in[0,2]$ such that $f(c)=3/2$.

Comment: Can you explain it more , I am still confused?

Comment: Apparently this function $f$ is not continuous (simply draw its graph). And there is a gap between the $y$-axis from $1$ to $2$, so $3/2$ is in between the gap, so there is none such $c$. And this function is clearly strictly increasing.

Comment: Thank you , I got it finally.